# How can I set the path for a QCompleter using a QFileSystemModel?

Tags: qt

I'm trying to make a QCompleter using a QFileSystemModel. The result is the QCompleter tries to auto complete starting from the root folder. I'd like to have the QCompleter start from a folder path of my choice.

I have the code below:

```
modelCompleter = new QCompleter(this);
fModel = new QFileSystemModel();
fModel->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath() + "/" + filepath);
modelCompleter->setModel(fModel);
ui->le_search->setCompleter(modelCompleter);
```

It seems that no matter what I try, setting the root path for the model results in no change. What should I be doing to change the path QCompleter shows?